# What elements are in the set $M=\{x \in \mathbb R \mid x^2+5x−6 \in (−1,\infty)\}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I want to ask what elements are in this set $M$:

$$M=\{x \in \mathbb R \mid x^2+5x−6 \in (−1,\infty)\}$$

The polynomial can be split into $(x-1)(x+6)$, but idk how to get an answer. I thought its $M=\{1\}$ because only
the number $1$ is from $(−1,\infty)$, but that turned out to be wrong.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: @Surb the inequality should be strict.

Comment: @Arthur  Yes, I read the question too quickly.

Comment: I don't really understand what do you mean by "because only the number 1 is from $(-1,+\infty)$". Do you know what $(-1,+\infty)$ means?

Comment: Thanks all for help. I know it but not in this context, that's why I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Would you please type what it means for us? Because if you type it out correctly, that's half of the problem solved.

Comment: Since $(-1, \infty)$ is the set of all real numbers larger than $-1$, the set $M$ contains all real numbers $x$ such that $x^2 + 5x - 6 > -1$.

Comment: Magenta, nevermind my comment, doesn't matter anymore.

Comment: Imagine if you will that you draw the graph of $f(x)=x^2+5x-6$.  Imagine if you will that you shade the entire half-plane corresponding to $g(x)>-1$.  The question is asking which $x$ values are such that a portion of the graph of $f(x)$ exists at that $x$ value somewhere in the shaded region.

Comment: Ahhh, I see now. Thank for help again.

Comment: The punchline will be that $f(x)$ will intersect the line $g(x)=-1$ in two positions... find those positions.  Then you will see that due to the nature in which $f(x)$ grows on either end, you will have all of the values of $x$ to the left of the first point of intersection and all of the values of $x$ to the right of the second point of intersection will be such that $f(x)>-1$

Comment: Aha, thank you. Is there a way how to end this post even thought it was answered via comment? I can answer my own question, not sure if that is right thing to do.

Comment: Providing a *self-answer* either directly in your posting, or in an *answer-box* is a good idea.

Comment: @MagentaBloabner yea answer your own question. It's good for the community and yourself.

Comment: Alright, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just write $x^{2}+5x-6>-1$ which is equivalent to $x^{2}+5x-5>0$ and calculating the roots of the binomial

$(x+\dfrac{5+\sqrt{5}}{2})(x-\dfrac{3\sqrt{5}-5}{2})>0$ which gives either

$x<\dfrac{-5-3\sqrt{5}}{2}$ or $x>\dfrac{-5+3\sqrt{5}}{2}$